# SELECT 2 entries from a JOIN into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables :

Manual:

```
ManualId | Stuff...
---------+----------
180      | Stuff...
```

ManualLang:

```
ManualLangId | ManualId | LangId | Description
-------------+----------+--------+-----------------------
1            | 180      | FR-CA  | Description française
2            | 180      | EN-CA  | English description
```

Lang:

```
LangId
---------
FR-CA
EN-CA
```

I am using a language table in order to easily add a new language to my application(s). The manualLang table is there to allow my manual attributes to have different language without duplicating my manual and avoiding having tons of attributes in my manual table for different language. Also, it will make it much easier for me in the future to add a new language this way without having to modify all the tables to add a language.

But I have a problem. On my MVC website I require to get a manual with both it's language. So in order to do this, I have to make a select query that would return me this:

```
Manual_Id | DescriptionFr         | DescriptionEn
----------------------------------|---------------------
180       | Description française | English description
```

So far, I can get my result with this query

```
SELECT  m.ManualId,
            mlFr.Description as 'DescriptionFr',
            mlEn.Description as 'DescriptionEn'
FROM    Manual m
left join   ManualLang mlFr ON m.ManualId = mlFr.ManualId
left join   ManualLang mlEn ON m.ManualId = mlEn.ManualId
WHERE   m.ManualId = 180 AND mlFr.LangId = 'FR-CA' AND mlEn.LangId = 'EN-CA'
```

My question is... Is it possible to do it in a cleaner way then this?

Should I be using a while? a CTE? a cursor? or is this the way I should do it? I'll have to replicate this for a lot of other queries in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a clear solution. You can change the query to move the join predicates to the `join` instead of the `where`. That's all.

```
select  m.ManualId
,       mlFr.Description as DescriptionFr
,       mlEn.Description as DescriptionEn
from    Manual m
left
outer
join    ManualLang mlFr
on      m.ManualId = mlFr.ManualId
and     mlFr.LangId = 'FR-CA'
left
outer
join    ManualLang mlEn
and     mlEn.LangId = 'EN-CA'
on      m.ManualId = mlEn.ManualId
where   m.ManualId = 180
```

Comment: Yes I should have done that, is this better or is Gordon Linoff solution better?

Comment: Hard to say. I would say mine performs better, but that is an educated guess. I would say: let the Explain Plan decide! :)

Comment: After testing both of them on SQL server, this version is very slightly slower but require less bytes transfer so I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single join and aggregataion:

```
SELECT  m.ManualId,
        max(case when ml.LangId = 'FR-CA' then ml.Description end) as DescriptionFr,
        max(case when ml.LangId = 'EN-CA' then ml.Description end) as DescriptionEn
FROM Manual m left join
     ManualLang ml
    ON m.ManualId = ml.ManualId
WHERE m.ManualId = 180 AND ml.LangId in ('FR-CA', 'EN-CA')
GROUP BY m.ManualId;
```

Note:  You should use single quotes only for string constants, not for column names.

EDIT:

This version let's you get everything you need:

```
SELECT m.*,  ml.DescriptionFr, ml.DescriptionEn
FROM Manual m left join
     (select ml.ManualId,
             max(case when ml.LangId = 'FR-CA' then ml.Description end) as DescriptionFr,
             max(case when ml.LangId = 'EN-CA' then ml.Description end) as DescriptionEn
      from ManualLang ml
      where ml.ManualId = 180 and ml.LangId in ('FR-CA', 'EN-CA')
      group by ml.ManualId
     ) ml
     ON m.ManualId = ml.ManualId;
```

Comment: I feel dumb that I forgot about GROUP BY ._. This work perfectly thank you. :)

Comment: After trying this on my app, there is a slight problem with it. My manual table got more then just ManualId in it and got about ~20 different attributes that I need to get in the select by doing SELECT m.* instead of m.ManualId. Is there a way to make the GROUP BY group by all the row from the manual?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it works nice and clean now. :)